# Connecting through Remote Desktop from Windows 7 Ultimate to a machine running Windows 2003 server

Tags: windows-7, desktop, connection, remote

So I have a machine running Windows Server 2003 R2 and another machine running Windows 7 Ultimate on the same LAN.

What I'm trying to do is simply use remote desktop connection to connect FROM my Windows 7 machine to the one running Windows 2003 server. What I've done so far and has not worked as of yet is:

-On Windows 2003 server:

- System -> Remote tab -> Turn on remote Assistance + Enable Remote Desktop on this computer

  - Then I selected the remote users that I wanted to allow to connect. I have a local account that is the same in all regards as the one on my Windows 7 machine. I added him.

-On the Windows 7  Machine:

- System -> Remote Settings -> Allow connections from computers running any version of mstsc (Did this just to try to connect from the win2003 machine and it worked)

I've been reading material from Microsoft on how to enable mstsc on win2003 and from that it seems that I've already done what should be done.

I can connect from Windows 2003 to the one running Windows 7 but not in the opposite direction. The error I get is that either the computer is not online, doesn't have mstsc enabled or isn't connected to a network.

Comment: This is not the right place for this question, as stackoverflow is more for programming-related questions.  That said, have you checked your firewall settings between the two?  Your culprit is likely the settings on the 2K3 server.

Comment: Can you successfully ping the IP address of the server from your Windows 7 machine?  If so, can you remote desktop to the server by IP address too?

Comment: Ah yeah sorry about that, first time posting so didn't realize. And the firewall settings were the culprit (how did I not realize that). Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Windows Server 2003 machine, you'll likely need to disable Windows firewall, or allow RDP through it.

If that doesn't work, ensure that you don't have it set to require NTLM2 on the Windows 7 box.